# average of an array

Tags: matlab, average

I have a matrix with 4 rows and 400,000 columns. I need to obtain the average of 4 successive rows. That is, average of row 1 to row 4, row 5 to 8, etc.

The 4 columns should be maintained as such. I know that this may be a kindergarten level problem, but I appreciate any hints to write a program in Matlab; I have a little experience writing Matlab programs.

An example of the data can be as follows:

```
[1 2 3 2; 
 5 6 7 2;
 9 6 7 6;
 5 2 3 2;
 9 8 7 6;
 6 5 4 3; 
 4 3 2 1;
 9 8 7 6]
```

I want the result as:

```
[5 4 5 3],[7 6 5 4]
```

Comment: The community generally expects you to post some code demonstrating what you have tried yourself, and perhaps asking for help in correcting a part of that code. You can edit your question to do this by clicking the "edit" link above.

Comment: What is it now? 4 rows 400k columns or 4 columns and 400k rows? looks like the latter...

Answer (score 2):

It is not entirely clear to me how your data is layed out, so I'll give you a solution to what I think you mean.

Suppose you have

```
a = [
    1   2   3   4    %# row 1
    2   3   4   5 
    3   4   5   6 
    4   5   6   7    %# row 4
    5   6   7   8    %# row 5
    ...
    ];               %# row m
```

and you want the average down the columns of rows 1 through 4, 5 through 8, etc.
You can do that simply by

```
averages = reshape(mean(reshape(a,4,4,[])),[],4)
```

breakdown:

```
A = reshape(a,4,4,[])
```

rearranges the data in your matrix into a 3D array. Each 3D "layer" of this array is a `4x4` matrix.

```
B = mean(A)
```

This takes the average along the columns (direction `1`). Read up on `help mean` for more information.

```
C = reshape(B,[],4)
```

This rearranges the array of averages back to a `Nx4` matrix, where `N=m/4`.